# Convert date-based NSString to NSDateComponents

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

Is it possible to parse out date components from an `NSString`-based date? For instance, if I have an `NSDateFormatter` with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZZ`, how can I get an `NSDateComponents` object from this string directly?

Specifically, I'd like to preserve timezones, and differentiate this `NSDateComponents` object with one created from the `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Comment: Create an `NSDate` from the `NSString` using an `NSDateFormatter`. Then get the `NSDateComponents` from the `NSDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Not so directly, but with a few steps:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZZ"];

NSString *dateString = @"2016-03-15 12:00:00.000 +0800";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitTimeZone fromDate:date];

NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [components timeZone];
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the timezone from the original date.

Comment: The timezone is stored in the `[components timeZone]`, what's the problem?

Comment: It's not the same timezone as the input string.